# How to set up a timer?

Tags: c#, timer

I have multiple object instances that I am trying to make run in a loop one after another using a timer. I have been talking to chatGPT for hours now and it's not able to help me.

Here is my code:

```
public class Program
{
    private static OpenSeaApiClient openSeaApiClient;
    private static Timer timer;
    private static int counter = 1;

    static async Task Main()
    {
        string apiKey = "myApiKey";
        openSeaApiClient = new OpenSeaApiClient(apiKey);

        // Set up a timer to run every 10 seconds
        timer = new Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).TotalMilliseconds);
        timer.Elapsed += async (sender, e) => await TimerElapsedAsync();
        timer.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit.");

        // Stop the timer when exiting the program
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Dispose();
    }

    private static async Task TimerElapsedAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Counter: {counter++}");

        var KarafuruXhypebeastXatmos = new Collection(openSeaApiClient, "karafuru-x-hypebeast-x-atmos", "0x32F2a60942E7563CFC42766018641C6C6b10830E", OfferVariables.initialValueOfferKarafuruXhypebeastXatmos);
        await KarafuruXhypebeastXatmos.ExecuteAsync();

        var BricktopiansByLawDegree = new Collection(openSeaApiClient, "bricktopians-by-law-degree", "0x9eEeAF684E228C2D5C89435e010acC02c41Dc86B", OfferVariables.initialValueOfferBricktopiansByLawDegree);
        await BricktopiansByLawDegree.ExecuteAsync();

//more instances

    }
```

When I run it it goes to the end of Main() and it stops. It never starts with TimerElapsedAsync(). And what I want is the processes in TimerElapsedAsync() to be executed one by one in a loop using the timer indefinatlety. Since the period of the timer is now set to 10 seconds, what I want to happen is after the end of the Main() method to immidiately start TimerElapsedAsync() and after the last process in TimerElapsedAsync() is executed to wait 10 seconds and start from the 1st process again. I guess I can use while (true) loop, but this will use my memory and as far as I know is not a good solution.
Please help me. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10000).TotalMilliseconds`, which means your timer is set to trigger every 10,000 seconds (approximately every 166 minutes), not every 10 seconds. To have the timer trigger every 10 seconds, you should use `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).TotalMilliseconds`.

Also you immediately stop the timer after you have stareted it.
Add a

`Console.ReadKey()` after the `Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit.");`

Try this one

```csharp
static async Task Main()
{
    string apiKey = "myApiKey";
    openSeaApiClient = new OpenSeaApiClient(apiKey);

    // Set up a timer to run every 10 seconds
    timer = new Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).TotalMilliseconds);
    timer.Elapsed += async (sender, e) => await TimerElapsedAsync();
    timer.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey(); // Waiting for user to exis

    // Stop the timer when exiting the program
    timer.Stop();
    timer.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I fixed the Milliseconds and added Console.ReadKey() after the Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit."); It works now! Thank you! Also in the code snippet you pasted you wrote Console.ReadLine() instead of Console.ReadKey(). Fix it if you want so other people don't get confused.

Comment: You're welcome. @paro

`Console.ReadKey` and `Console.ReadLine` would both work, but I will change this in order to don't get others confused. Thank you :)